# PPC's real output value

Tags: nonexpert, classical-economics, aggregate-supply

Does every point on the PPC have the same real output value? If not, then what point on the PPC does the long-run aggregate supply represent? LRAS is supposed to be vertical on the real GDP if the economy is producing efficiently, but every point on the PPC efficient. Every article I've read so far doesn't give a clear answer to this.

- [Long-run Aggregate Supply on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/economics-finance-domain/ap-macroeconomics/national-income-and-price-determinations/long-run-aggregate-supply-ap/a/lesson-summary-long-run-aggregate-supply#:%7E:text=The%20LRAS%20represents%20a%20point,its%20current%20stock%20of%20resources.):

> The LRAS represents a point on a country’s PPC, translated into the AD-AS model. Every point on the PPC represents the maximum sustainable capacity for production in an economy. This value of real GDP represents the economy’s maximum sustainable capacity given its current stock of resources.

- [Aggregate Supply - Boundless Economics](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-economics/chapter/aggregate-supply/):

> In the long-run only capital, labor, and technology impact the aggregate supply curve because at this point everything in the economy is assumed to be used optimally.

- [Aggregate Supply - Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/aggregatesupply.asp)

> In the long run, however, aggregate supply is not affected by the price level and is driven only by improvements in productivity and efficiency.

In a Khan Academy exercise, it says that both points on the example PPC is worth $6 billion, but I don't know whether this is true for all cases.
[image]

I really don't understand what I'm missing or if the LRAS is all theoretical anyway and this is just a pointless question.

Thanks in advance!